# Xamarin Build Host Not working in IOS Yosemite 10.10

Tags: windows, xamarin, osx-yosemite

I cannot connect to build host in Yosemite 10.10. Everything was fine and working until I updated my OSX from mavericks to Yosemite. Does anyone have a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fix for that, please read here:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26340/fixed-os-x-yosemite-the-pin-you-entered-was-invalid#latest

Comment: Thanx Let me check :)

Comment: It's working. Quit and re-open Build Host after Update on the Mac was the key point for me.